# Control access to Case(incident) in MSCRM 2015

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

We came across the scenario where we need to control the access to the Case records based on value selected in the field.

There are 2 users U1 and U2 under the Business Units B1 and B2 respectively. Both the users having Organization level full access on Contact and Account entities and Business Unit level full access on Case entity.

User U1 created a Case C1 for the Customer A1 and User U2 created a Case for the Customer A2. We got a requirement, where users U1 & U2 should be having access to C2 & C1 respectively. But, since both of them having read access to A1 & A2, they can still access the Cases C1 & C2 (which are created for the Customers A1 & A2).

So, is there any way to control the access to the Cases irrespective of the access to Customers (Account & Contact)?

It would resolve the issue if there is any workaround to control access based on the field value selected as we have Category field on Case.

Appreciate if any solution for this.
Thanks,

Comment: Can you use teams?

Comment: Since both BUs have access to Customers(Contact and Account), cannot control by Teams. I fixed it by writing Pre Retrieve Multiple Plugin Case to modify the Query Expression to show only the Cases based on the Category. :)